# Blank White screen and ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

Tags: three.js

I have been practicing 3d modeling in few years without coding at. As, the demand for loading ready made 3d models to 3js is increasing, I have decided to start coding. After 2 days of trial and error with my first code, I am sharing with you the code that does not seem to work properly. I am not sure where the error is because part of it is HTML and the other one is a three.js script. Note that, the obj file was converted to JavaScript. I have been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtRrYUAd8rs which does not show the entire html texts. So I decided to add the HTML of https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene which shows the basic doc for setting up a scene. Once I open up the html file in the browser an errors of Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined! I found out that some one in this world was able to solve this error using UMD version of Three.js but I can not see how it should be stated in the html file. You may have a look at my code below;

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My first three.js app</title>
<style>
body { margin: 0; } 
canvas { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="Desktop/convert/three.js"></script><script>
// Our Javascript will go here.
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var particleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
particleMaterial.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/convert/china-politics.jpg');
particleMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
var itmArr = [];

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try replacing your local `three.js` file with [this one](https://unpkg.com/three@0.122.0/build/three.js). You can recognize umd files because they don't use `require()` or `import`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering my question. I am not sure if I did it correctly or not because after replacing the content of three.js file with the content that are visible in your link, I still see the same blank white screen on my browser. I am assuming that you are referring to this line of code. `<script src="Desktop/convert/three.js"></script><script>`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have to be a local file, though. Do you see errors in your console or has that disappeared?

Comment: Yes there is another error:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   three.js:1

Comment: Well, what do you think that means? Just replace `Desktop.convert.three.js` with `https://unpkg.com/three@0.122.0/build/three.js`